# Recurrence relationship program in r

Tags: python, statistics

Consider the problem where a family will have kids until they have s sons and d daughters.

Using the recurrence relationship determine E(N(s,d)) the number of children the family can expect to have before reaching their goal of s sons and d daughters.

I started by coming up with the recursive formula

E(N(s,d)) = 1 + p*E(N(s-1,d)) + q*E(N(s,d-1))

How would I go about creating a program to execute this formula in r. I am having trouble because each recursion branches off 2 new calls (one for the s-1 case and one for the d-1 case) so I am not having much luck in trying to implement a useful solution.

I wrote a program in python to simulate the answer and it looks as follows:

```py
from random import random
list_of_results = []
for j in range(100000):
    m = 0
    n=0
    i=0
    while n < 3 or m < 2:
        if random() >.5:
            n=n+1
        else:
            m=m+1
        i=i+1
    list_of_results.append(i)
print(sum(list_of_results)/len(list_of_results))
```

This is a homework problem so i am not really looking for an answer per say -- just been spinning my wheels on why I'm not getting expected results

Comment: This feels like a homework question.  What have you tried?  Also, read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: BTW, recursion works in R, but it does not optimize for tail-recursion (e.g., reduction of stack growth) or other problems that incorrect recursive heuristics can introduce. Recursion can be done with multiple recursive calls, where calculating the Fibonacci sequence comes to mind.

Comment: Hey @DanY see my edit to the problem, you are correct, this is a homework problem, thank you for the link, I have edited to follow the suggestions

Comment: Tag editted. The edited version no longer applies to R and arguably should be deleted since the error had little to do with statistics or recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was in my evaluation of when d or s = 0, I had the wrong formula. After tracing it through on paper I realized my mistake there. Fixed the formula for those cases and now its returning the correct answer